# How Can I Remove Custom Post Type Slug From URL

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

There are many different solutions available and I have tried a bunch of them, but none of them seems to work for me.

That is what I have,

I have made a CPT "Canada" that has different provinces as `Categories`, and each `Category` has different cities as `Posts`. My permalink structure looks like this `url/%category%/%postname%/` or `url/Canada/Alberta/Edmonton`. And basically I want to remove the CPT Slug from url, i.e, "Canada" and it should look like `url/Alberta/Edmonton`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is via .htaccess. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710411/how-to-remove-part-of-url-with-htaccess